# Absolute minimum code to get a valid oauth_signature populated in Python

Tags: python, oauth

**What is required:** I want a valid Authorization Header

What I have: consumer key ,consumer_secret, access_token, token_secret

Summary: I simply need to populate the oauth_signature portion of the Authorization header for a RESTful service. How do I do it?